# remove duplicate name submenu link from the custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, admin-menu

I was wondering what would be the proper way to remove submenu with duplicate name in custom post type in the admin. I tried to use `remove_submenu_page()` however since its a duplicate it is showing same slug for menu and submenu `/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=portfolio` and to use that function my understanding slugs should be different

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code seems to work and remove duplicate name from Porfolio custom post type

```
'all_items'     => __( '' )
```